# How to tell which form module called your class

Tags: excel, vba

Suppose, for instance, that I want a method that adds a ComboBox. Maybe I try this

```
Public Sub AddComboBox()
    Dim cb As MSForms.ComboBox

    Set cb = <Calling form module>.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1")
End Sub
```

How can I get `<Calling form module>`?

Comment: "You can't" appears to be the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, pass the instance of the form to class method. Unlike others, I'm going to add:

- Declare the argument AS
  MSForms.UserForm
- Pass the parameter ByVal.
- If calling from the UserForm itself,
  use the `Me` keyword in the call.

He's a brief example:

```
' <Module1.bas>
Option Explicit
Sub Main()

  UserForm1.Show vbModeless
  UserForm2.Show vbModeless

End Sub
' </Module1.bas>

' <UserForm1.frm>
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
  Dim c As Class1
  Set c = New Class1
  c.AddComboBox Me
End Sub
' </UserForm1.frm>

' <UserForm2.frm>
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
  Dim c As Class1
  Set c = New Class1
  c.AddComboBox Me
End Sub
' </UserForm2.frm>

' <Class1.cls>
Option Explicit

Public Sub AddComboBox(ByVal MSForms_UserForm As MSForms.UserForm)
    Dim cb As MSForms.ComboBox    
    Set cb = MSForms_UserForm.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1")
End Sub
' </Class1.cls>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're writing this the wrong way.  Instead of trying to determine who called the method, just pass the `<Calling Form Module>` to `AddComboBox()` as an argument.  Like this:

```
Public Sub CallToAddComboBox()
    AddComboBox(<Calling form module>)
End Sub

Public Sub AddComboBox(CallingFormModule as <Module Object Type>)
    Dim cb As MSForms.ComboBox

    Set cb = CallingFormModule.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1")
End Sub
```

Comment: I work in Access and I can't 100% validate the code.  But LFSR is certainly on the right track -- pass the calling object in as an argument of the function.